# How can I show contents in "/index.html" by editing .htaccess when the user accesses to a directory URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-codes

I've a .htaccess in root directory of a domain. I've code below in this .htaccess file:

`DirectorySlash Off`

When the user accesses to any directory URL in this domain, I hope server can always forever show contents in `/index.html` with HTTP status code 200. This `/index.html` file is located in root directory. Please do not let server redirect the user to the file `/index.html`.

How can I achieve this by editing .htaccess file? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Yazmat. But the index.html file which I wanna show is in the root directory. Not every directory's corresponding index.html. Do you need to change your answer's codes a little bit? I just changed original post.

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW. The codes `^(.*[^/])?$` looks like it is not necessary? Can I delete it?

Comment: You are welcome, about the code, I tought you only want to redirect urls without a slash (my mistake I didn't read well the question), I removed it

Comment: Hi, Yazmat. When I access to a directory which doesn't exist, I get 404. You know I wanna get 200 and show the contents in root file `/index.html`. How can I cancel 404 and return 200? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.*)$ index.html?directory=$1&file=$2
```

It will also parse a "directory" `GET` variable as well as a "file" `GET` variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :-) But I think Yazmat's answer is right.